# Book Identification: Future Earth Covered in Cemeteries?

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a science fiction piece about a far future Earth where every square inch of the planet was a cemetery, memorial or shrine - where little by little the entire planet's surface became hallowed ground that you couldn't do anything with as you had to respect those buried there, or those who died there, or those who were otherwise commemorated there.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You can take the [tour] to get an understanding of how the site works. This is a good start, but it may help if you can provide more details. Take a look at [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/) for suggestions that may prompt more info from your memory. For example, do you remember when you read the story? Was it part of a full novel, a short-story anthology, or something online?

Answer (score 11):

This appears to be Clifford Simak's [*Cemetery World*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GR5QXI),

> In all the recent literature of Earth -- recent being the last thousand years or so --there was seldom any mention, anywhere, of the rest of Earth at all. The Earth was Cemetery, if one excepted those last few places of historic and cultural interest that were so highly advertised and promoted by the Pilgrim Tours.

Of course it turns out to be more complicated than that.

[Link to copy on Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/cemeteryworld00sima)